# delete rows on a csv file depending on pattern python

Tags: python, csv

I am new at handling csv files with python and I want to write code that allows me to do the following: I have a pattern as:
`pattern="3-5;7;10-16"`(which may vary) 
and I want to delete (in that case) rows 3 to 5 , 7 and 10 to 16
does any one have an idea how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simply delete lines from a csv. Instead, you have to read it in and then write it back with the accepted values. The following code works:

```
import csv

pattern="3-5;7;10-16"

off = []
for i in pattern.split(';'):
    if '-' in i:
        off += range(int(i.split('-')[0]),int(i.split('-')[1])+1)
    else:
        off += [int(i)]

with open('test.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    reader = [','.join(item) for i,item in enumerate(reader) if i+1 not in off]

print reader

with open('input.txt', 'w') as f2:
    for i in reader:
        f2.write(i+'\n')
```